# set jupyterhub notebook_dir to s3 on emr 5.16

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, jupyterhub

is there a way to redirect the **notebook-dir** to **s3** in the JSON configuration file of an EMR-Cluster befor start the cluster. I used the following classification: "jupyter-notebook-conf" and set the following option:
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir "s3://[bucket]/path"

That creates the config file:
"/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py"
with the given entry, but with no success.

Earlier I could use the option **--notebook-dir** when I installed the jupyterhub  manually, but now I try to use the preinstalled jupyterhub service of the EMR-Cluster
(see: [Run Jupyter Notebook and JupyterHub on Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/big-data/running-jupyter-notebook-and-jupyterhub-on-amazon-emr/))

Answer (score 0):

not supported on 5.16

5.17 allows this by adding this config classification

```
[
    {
        "Classification": "jupyter-s3-conf",
        "Properties": {
            "s3.persistence.enabled": "true",
            "s3.persistence.bucket": "MyJupyterBucket"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now, I wrote a script to get it working, but this looks much better. :D

Comment: @Steven does it actually work for you? It seems like the container running jupyterhub doesn't inherit the credentials to S3. I added them manually (`export...`). Then, it turned out that `dask` and `toolz` are not installed in the container. I added them as well and still: no success.

Comment: @Dror this **does** work for me.  If you believe credentials are an issue I would look at the IAM role and SGs associated with the EMR master